# Python: Cancel object creation during initialization

Tags: python

I'm creating a list of objects, and if any have some undesirable data while they're being initialized, I'd like to immediately cancel their initialization, and move on to the next object. Is there a best practice for something like this in Python?

```
data = [good, bad]
theList = [myObject(some_data) for some_data in data]

# I'd like myObject to determine if it should create itself, after some data parsing.
```

Should I just return nothing from `__new__` ? Or do I just need to separate out the data validation logic from myObject..? Or..?

Thanks!

Context: Given a folder path, I'm checking a bunch of stuff in sequence (is the basename formatted correctly, if so, does a certain file exist, if so, parse it...etc)

Comment: how are you checking for undesirable data?

Comment: did you find a way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a generator. This will create the object whether or not the data is valid, but retain it based on a flag set during the init.
e.g.,

```
data = [good, bad]
theList = [obj for obj in (MyObject(some_data) for some_data in data) if obj.data_is_valid]
```

Answer (score 4):

Like the other answer said, validate the data before creating objects. Somewhat like this:

```
def validate(data):
    if data_is_good: return True
    else: return False

data = [good, bad]
theList = [myObject(some_data) for some_data in data if validate(some_data)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can raise an exception inside the class' `__init__`. Note, however, that you can no longer use a list comprehension (which is no huge loss).

Answer (score 1):

You should check / validate if you have correct data, prior to feeding the data to your object constructor. If data is invalid you should raise an error, eg `raise ValueError` or your own custom exception. Only when the data is valid should you can with creating the object. in addition you can also raise the exception from your class object's **init** method too.